# Parse Backgroundjob Matching

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm currently programming a background job for my Parse Database. 
The Database contains lots of users in the User class. All user have a 'location' column and an 'offer' and 'search' column. 'offer' and 'search' store an array of strings. 
What it should do is the following:
The background job should go through all the users and check for users close to them and then check if these users match on specific skills. So if someone has "example" in 'search' and someone else has "example" in 'offer' these user match and both get a notification.

---

1. The location query does not choose users close to each other
2. If a user does not "offer" anything, but "searches" for something he does not get a notification
3. It should not constantly send push notifications when two users are close to each other (only once)

-

```
Parse.Cloud.job("backgroundJob", function(request, status) {
var queryAllUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var targetList = []; //new Array();
queryAllUser.each(function(user) {
    var queryMatch = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryMatch.withinKilometers("location", user.get("location"), 0.1);

    //if(user.get("search") != null){
    queryMatch.containedIn("offer", user.get("search"));
    //                                  }
    return queryMatch.first().then(function(firstUser) {
        if (firstUser != null) {
            console.error("THIS IS THE FIRST USER: " + firstUser.get("name"));
        }
        if (firstUser) {
            targetList.push(user);
        }
    });
}).then(function() {

        console.error("Length of TargetList: " + targetList.length);

        if (targetList[0] != null && targetList.length != 1) {

            var queryTarget = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
            queryTarget.containedIn('user', targetList);
            return Parse.Push.send({
                where: queryTarget,
                data: {
                    alert: "Found a Match!",
                    badge: "Increment",
                    pushType: "1",
                }
            }, {
                success: function() {
                    status.success("Send the Pushes!");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    status.error(error);
                }
            });
        }
        status.success("did the job!");
    },
    function(error) {
        status.error("error:" + error.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: any error messages shown in the parse error logs? can you reformat your code so the tabs don't make it unreadable and the indents make sense?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? And please have your editor use spaces for indentation. Never tabs...

Comment: No error messages shown in the parse error logs. Reformatted the code and add the problems.